# Handling unique methods of Subclasses

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a component in a software that can be described by an interface / virtual class.
Which non-virtual subclass is needed is decided by a GUI selection at runtime.

Those subclasses have unique methods, for which is makes no sense to give them a shared interface (e.g. collection of different data types and hardware access).

A minimal code example looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// interface base class
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void shared()=0;
};

// some subclasses with shared and unique methods
class A : public Base
{
public:
    void shared()
    {
        cout << "do A stuff\n";
    }
    
    void methodUniqueToA()
    {
        cout << "stuff unique to A\n";
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    void shared()
    {
        cout << "do B stuff\n";
    }
    
    void methodUniqueToB()
    {
        cout << "stuff unique to B\n";
    }
};

// main
int main()
{
    // it is not known at compile time, which subtype will be needed. Therefore: pointer has base class type:
    shared_ptr<Base> basePtr;
    
    // choose which object subtype is needed by GUI - in this case e.g. now A is required. Could also have been B!
    basePtr = make_shared<A>();
    
    // do some stuff which needs interface functionality... so far so good
    basePtr->shared();
    
    // now I want to do methodUniqueToA() only if basePtr contains type A object
    // this won't compile obviously:
    basePtr->methodUniqueToA(); // COMPILE ERROR
    
    // I could check the type using dynamic_pointer_cast, however this ist not very elegant!
    if(dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(basePtr))
    {
        dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(basePtr)->methodUniqueToA();
    }
    else
    if(dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(basePtr))
    {
        dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(basePtr)->methodUniqueToB();
    }
    else
    {
        // throw some exception
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Methods methodUniqueTo*() could have different argument lists and return data which is omitted here for clarity.

I suspect that this problem isn't a rare case. E.g. for accessing different hardware by the different subclasses while also needing the polymorphic functionality of their container.
How does one generally do this?

For the sake of completeness: the output (with compiler error fixed):

```
do A stuff
stuff unique to A
```

Comment: "which is omitted here for clarity." imho the example would be more clear if the methods had different signatures, because in your code it isnt apparent why those methods cannot be made part of `Base`

Comment: also strictly speaking it isnt polymorphism when you need to know the exact type to be able to call a method

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `enum` which will represent the derived class. For example [this](https://onlinegdb.com/EP0rpFW1J):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

enum class DerivedType
{
    NONE = 0,
    AType,
    BType
};


class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        mType = DerivedType::NONE;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default; //You should have a virtual destructor :)
    virtual void shared() = 0;
     DerivedType GetType() const { return mType; };
protected:
    DerivedType mType;
    
};

// some subclasses with shared and unique methods
class A : public Base
{
public:
   A()
   {
     mType = DerivedType::AType;
   } 

   void shared()
   {
       cout << "do A stuff\n";
   }
   
   void methodUniqueToA()
   {
       cout << "stuff unique to A\n";
   }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
   B()
   {
     mType = DerivedType::BType;
   } 
   void shared()
   {
       cout << "do B stuff\n";
   }
   
   void methodUniqueToB()
   {
       cout << "stuff unique to B\n";
   }
};

// main
int main()
{
   shared_ptr<Base> basePtr;
   basePtr = make_shared<B>();
   basePtr->shared();
   
   // Here :)
   if(basePtr->GetType() == DerivedType::AType)
       static_cast<A*>(basePtr.get())->methodUniqueToA();
   else if(basePtr->GetType() == DerivedType::BType)
       static_cast<B*>(basePtr.get())->methodUniqueToB();

   return 0;
}
```

You can store an enum and initialize it at the constructor. Then have a Getter for that, which will give you the Type. Then a simple static cast after getting the type would do your job!

Answer (score 0):

The goal of using polymorphism for the client is to control different objects with a single way. In other words, the client do not have to pay any attention to the difference of each object. That way, checking the type of each object violates the basic goal.

To achieve the goal, you will have to :

- write the concrete method(methodUniqueToX()).
- write a wrapper of the concrete method.
- name the wrapper method abstract.
- make the method public and interface/abstract.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void shared()=0;
    virtual void onEvent1()=0;
    virtual void onEvent2()=0;
};

// some subclasses with shared and unique methods
class A : public Base
{
private:
    void methodUniqueToA()
    {
        cout << "stuff unique to A\n";
    }
public:
    void shared()
    {
        cout << "do A stuff\n";
    }    
    void onEvent1()
    {   
        this.methodUniqueToA()
    }
    void onEvent2()
    {   
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
private:
    void methodUniqueToB()
    {
        cout << "stuff unique to B\n";
    }
public:
    void shared()
    {
        cout << "do B stuff\n";
    }
    void onEvent1()
    {   
    }
    void onEvent2()
    {   
        methodUniqueToB()
    }
};
```